# Issue with Gizmo Alignment on Bone Tail Selection in Blender Armature

Tags: armature, gizmo

[image]

Hello everyone,

I've encountered an issue in Blender while working with Armature, specifically when selecting Bone Tails. Despite setting the Gizmo's pivot point to 'Active Element', the Gizmos continue to align with the Bone Head instead of the selected Tail. I've made sure to select only the Tail part in Edit Mode, expecting the Gizmos to appear at the Tail's location for manipulation, but this hasn't been the case.

Here are the steps I've followed:

Switched to Edit Mode and selected the Bone Tail precisely.
Changed the Gizmo's pivot point setting to 'Active Element', hoping it would align the Gizmo with the selected Bone Tail.
Unfortunately, the Gizmo still aligns with the Bone Head, which is not what I'm aiming for. I want to be able to manipulate the bone from the Tail's position using the Gizmos centered on the Tail.

I'm using Blender version 4.0.2

Has anyone experienced this issue or can provide insight into what might be causing this? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that changing the pivot point from 'Active Element' to 'Median Point' unexpectedly resolved the issue.